handling multiple scroll event in spline
i want to give multiple scroll event in spline, more precisely i have made and object which have three states first one in the center of the screen second one in the right and third one in the left of the screen i want to change the states one by one first from the center to right then left, for which i have used two different scroll event first one is from center to right and second from right to left, but when to playing the scene and scrolling the element goes from center to left directly and when scrolling up then left to right how can i fix this
wanted to give two scroll event in spline in which one scroll event transition from state1 to 2 and second scroll event transition from state 2 to 3 how can i do it here is the image for both the events
